# Unix Bash Script Display Words From File Separated by Character

Tags: bash, unix, sed, grep

I am currently working on a bash script which requires me to display words from a file separated by a tilde (~) character using grep or sed.  In my script I have to display different fields for each word.  For example I will need to echo "Word 1: " followed by the first word in the file, on separate lines in the script.  This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Word 1: " >> print.txt
echo "Word 2: " >> print.txt
echo "Word 3: " >> print.txt
```

etc.

I need to read the words from another file that contains just words separated by ~ and does not have any spaces.  This will be included after the "Word 1: " and before the append operator.  I have been looking around and it looks like I need to do something with the grep -o command.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How about awk? `awk 'BEGIN {RS="~"} {print "Word " NR ": " $0}' wordlist.txt` will do from your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [awk](http://www.joeldare.com/wiki/using_awk_on_csv_files).

```
echo "Word 1: " `awk -F '~' '{print $1}' print.txt`
echo "Word 2: " `awk -F '~' '{print $2}' print.txt`
echo "Word 3: " `awk -F '~' '{print $3}' print.txt`
```

If you want it to loop infinitely over all items in the tilde separated list, you'll use a loop in awk.

```
awk -F '~' '{ for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {print "Word " i ": " $i;} }' print.txt
```

What you are currently doing with the `>>` is actually appending to the end of that file. If you executed what you have, your **print.txt** would end up looking like

```
word~anotherword~etc
Word 1:
Word 2:
Word 3:
```

**EDIT based on commented clarification:**
Ah I see, okay then, this awk loop will output the list, then all you need to do is [redirect](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection) that to the print file. I understand now why you were using that. It will look like this:

```
awk -F '~' '{ for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { print "Word " i ": " $i; } }' words.txt > print.txt
```

Comment: I am trying to append to print.txt which is a different file.  For example, if the words are stored in words.txt, I want to read the words from that file and store them in print.txt.